# Import bootstrap CSS in React failed to compile

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React js by following a tutorial and creating react app via create-react-app with my terminal.

The problem is occuring with importing bootstrap to my code, I can't figure it out.
How I installed bootstrap is:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.1.3
```

App.js code and importing bootstrap :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 className="alert alert-warning">Welcome</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

On compiling I get error:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css)
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop\ReactAgile\reactxxx\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js' in 'C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop\ReactAgile\reactxxx'
```

---

What I tried is: Installing different versions of bootstrap and importing them in my App.js file but same error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing the react-bootstrap library, add the CDN link in your HTML file, and import specific components as shown in the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/)

HTML

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

React

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. This does work, but in tutorial he shows this way with npm, I am not sure why is it not working with my example...

Comment: Hmm its possible the tutorial uses an old version of react-bootstrap and importing was different, not sure. glad its working

Comment: Tutorial uses: npm install bootstrap@4.1.3 and import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" inside App.js
 I am not huge fan of CDN way, but thanks, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to configure loading CSS and other file types. This worked for me in the terminal:

`yarn add babel-loader @babel/core --dev`

Comment: Lol... By using `yarn remove babel-loader @babel/core --dev` problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Silly Solution and I'm not sure why it worked but adding babel-loader and then removing it worked for me.

Add by running the below command

```
yarn add babel-loader @babel/core --dev
```

Then, remove using

```
yarn remove babel-loader @babel/core --dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me the following worked:

1. deleting `package-lock.json`
2. run `npm install`
3. run `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

yarn add/remove babel-loader @babel/core --dev works, not sure why?

packages, dependencies and lockfile all gets removed during yarn remove. As of now it works, so analyzing how, will be after learning React. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding babel and removing it like in the answer above :
Add it using:

```
yarn add babel-loader @babel/core --dev
```

Remove it using:

```
yarn remove babel-loader @babel/core --dev
```

In case it didn't work, try importing bootstrap in the *Index.js* file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```